# Identifying a set completely given some conditions

Tags: number-theory

A set S contains integers 1 and 2. S also contains all integers of the
form 3x+y where x and y are distinct elements of S, and every element
of S other than 1 and 2 can be obtained as above. What is S? Justify
your answer.

This is a question I came across while solving past question papers for an entrance exam. My approach has been to brute force write out the elements of the set which revealed no patterns.Other ways I have tried are trying to find a general term of the set which gives numbers of the type:

3x+y,  3x+y+3, 3x+y+6

This line of approach doesn't work either.

Any help or hint will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  What's the least integer not in $S$?  What are the next few integers not in $S$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions. Many users in this forum won't even read your question if it's not properly formatted, let alone help you.

Comment: Noted both comments. Will edit as soon as I can.

Comment: Claim: your set contains no multiples of $3$.  Can you see how you can justify why?  Does this lead you to a final answer?

Comment: After the $5$, the elements of the set follow a pretty obvious pattern, can you see it?

Comment: @lulu  yeah noticed the exclusion of all multiples of 3 and the number 4.